# How can I get my mouse pointer back without losing my session?

Tags: mouse-pointer

My mouse pointer has vanished (though the mouse is usable) and I have a multi-day calculation in progress on my Ubuntu 15.04 computer. So, how could I try to get my pointer back *without losing my current session*?

I have tried the following command but nothing changed:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

Comment: Try `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: @Liso Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this approach kills the session, which is something I mentioned in the question shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following procedure appears to work in Ubuntu 15.04. The X Server communicates with programs via the network socket `localhost:0`. The environment variable `DISPLAY` can be set to this socket, then, on resetting Unity, this socket can be picked up for communications again. So, on encountering an interface problem such as a missing mouse pointer or a frozen display, something like the following procedure could be attempted:

- Access tty1: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
- Set the environment variable `DISPLAY`: `DISPLAY=:0`
- Export the environment variable `DISPLAY`: `export DISPLAY`
- Reset Unity: `sudo unity --replace`